# Fetch JSON response back from GET api using HTTP Clinent

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

I am trying to fetch some response back after sending params to API using HTTP Module.`

```
let response = this.httpclient.get<JSONObject>('api_url',{params: param});
return response;
```

I should be getting a message back, Instead I am getting this back;

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: FilterOperator}_isScalar: false__proto__: Object
```

Comment: You should be getting an `Observable` of `JSONObject`.  https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response  and it seems like you are?

Comment: response.subscribe(data => console.log(data))